# How to do login authentication in ios

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

login action not happening though it doesn't show ANY ERROR if I hit login button without giving any credentials it login in to the welcome page how to overcome this ?

I'm using PHP as web service, it works correctly for REGISTRATION page stores all value in database but does not get authenticated

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let user = "user"
    let password = "password"

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER,method: .post)
        .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
            print(response.response as Any) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data as Any)     // server data
            print(response.result)

            if response.response?.statusCode == 200
            {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)

            }
            else
            {
                self.labelMessage.text = "incorrect"
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to setup local validation like empty fields in app side before send request to server.

Also setup validation at server side like password or username empty and provided inputs match with database store value.

If inputs empty or inputs not match with database inputs server need to give error to application.

Comment: i have done server side validation but not local validations, will u guide me up in local validation?? coz m new to this concept

Comment: Before send request to server you need to check for input fields..Like your textfield is empty or not.if it is empty you need to display alert to user.Ex.if(your textfield.isEmpty){display alert to user}

Comment: actually m not getting how to do local validation i understood the concept but not able to implement (coding)

Comment: you can check over https://github.com/PKrupa94/localValidation. clone repo and check it

Answer (score 0):

Please use breakpoint when click on login button whether it is going inside service request or not.

Thanks.

Comment: m gettin response from the server side too as SUCCESS